# Replicate Data-Driven model GA4 in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I new using GA4 in bigquery, im trying to get the sales by campaign (or source).

The following query return the expected data, sales for each campaign, but this data is not the same that Analytics show in the interface, the difference es huge.

```
SELECT

((SELECT ep.value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) ep 
WHERE key = 'campaign')) as campaign,

sum(
(SELECT value.int_value
FROM unnest(event_params)
WHERE key = "value" and event_name = "purchase") ) as sales

FROM

'analytics_######.events_*'

group by

campaign
```

After read a lot,  the problems is the difference of attribution model. GA4 use Data-Driven model by default but i dont have any idea of how get or calculate Data-Driven model.
I would appreciate if someone could help me or give some doc, video or tutorial.

Thanks in advance!